# On the Fourier Transform of the $x[n]=1$ fo all $n$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

For the input $x[n]=1$ for all $n$, how to get to this without any shortcuts? (I know we can use the "well-known" property of the periodic signals) I want to reach this final form using pure mathematics.

$$ X(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n] e^{-j\omega n} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-j\omega n}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} 2\pi \delta(\omega +2\pi k)$$

If fact, I want to know why we get:

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-j\omega n}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} 2\pi \delta(\omega +2\pi k)$$

Why the summation of the complex envelopes (the exponential one) can be expressed as the summation of the impulse function (the Dirac delta one)? How are they related?

Can I answer this question without resorting to the Fourier analysis?

Comment: What's wrong with Fourier analysis?  It is one of the most beautiful products of the 19th century!

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am just curious to know if there is anything else to use? It's like a black box or a loop. For instance, almost all the reference books that I see, they just say here is the final form and they evoke the periodic signals property to prove it. I cannot get how that converges to that! Also, my books are not related to Math but Engineering

Comment: You are using a lot of jargon that is unfamiliar to me (I'm a pure maths guy, so things like "impulses," "complex envelopes," and "periodic signals" are a bit of a mystery to me.  But the point of Fourier analysis is that it makes it possible to work with the wave equation (and therefore wave-like phenomena) very easily.  That being said, if you want to understand the nitty-gritty, a little bit of functional analysis goes a long way.  Do you know what an $L^p$ space is?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sorry for the terms, I just edited my last comment. Those come from my engineering background. I don't know about mathematics. No, I don't know what $L^p$ is. Is it representing a $p$ dimensional space?

Comment: $L^p$ is a function space; it has to do with how "integrable" a function is.  Let's go back a step---how do you feel about vector spaces?

Comment: You mean how I am able to imagine more than 3 dimensions? I know a little bit about vectors, by the way.